# Can you remove the bottom section (navigation arrows and sheet name) from the bottom of a Google Sheet when it is embedded?

Tags: google-sheets, iframe

I published a single page of a Google Sheet to the web and am using the embed option. I'm trying to get rid of the grey navigation bar at the bottom. Other suggestions I've found say that adding "&rm=minimal" at the end of the URL should get rid of it but that doesn't seem to work here.

[What the embedded sheet looks like on a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg2Iy.png)

Here the code provided by Google Sheets with a few edits that I have added:

```
<iframe width="600px" height="350px" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSX-LmmuDoGXvJrAJ--r0sCXBuRkJ9IOhMSRGE-R0mPSdqnYC6OHPMe40UEhJAET8GS0cIc7QWMGrSk/pubhtml?gid=902947501&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false&chrome=false&rm=minimal"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative to embedding.

The embed will have very limited options and as far as I can see, there are no options to remove the footer section. That said, there is a way to get simple table data to display on your data, although it does take some more code than a simple embed, the advantage is that you can customize its appearance completely.

In the same menu where you get the embed link you can also publish your sheet as a CSV file:

[image]

Which will give you a link like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/[ID_NUMBER]/pub?gid=1417861555&single=true&output=csv
```

Which you can use in your HTML like this:

```html
<!--Some basic Styling-->
<style>
  table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border: 2px black solid;
      font: 12px sans-serif;
  }

  td {
      border: 1px black solid;
      padding: 5px;
  }
</style>

<script>
  let url = "[LINK]"; // <<--- PASTE LINK HERE

  // Get the data
  fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => resp.body)
    .then((stream) => new Response(stream))
    .then((response) => response.blob())
    .then((blob) => {
      blob.type = "text/csv";
      return blob.text();
    })
    // turn csv into 2D array
    .then((text) => csvTo2DArray(text))
    // make a table
    .then((tableArray) => makeTable(tableArray))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));

  // turn the csv into a two-dimensional array
  function csvTo2DArray(csv){
    const rows = csv.split("\n")
    const output = rows.map(col => col.split(','))
    return output
  }
  
  // use the two dimensional array to append a table to the web page.
  function makeTable(tableArray){
    const headers = tableArray.shift();
    const rows = tableArray;

    let table = document.createElement('table')
    let tableHeader = document.createElement('tr')
    
    headers.forEach(header => {
      let headerElement = document.createElement('th')
      headerElement.innerText = header
      tableHeader.appendChild(headerElement)
    })

    table.appendChild(tableHeader)

    rows.forEach(row => {
      let rowElement = document.createElement('tr')
      row.forEach(data => {
        let dataElement = document.createElement('td')
        dataElement.innerText = data
        rowElement.appendChild(dataElement)
      })
      table.appendChild(rowElement)
    })
    
    document.body.appendChild(table)
  }
</script>
```

By pasting the above exactly into an HTML file, and then having this data in the spreadsheet:

[image]

It will render a web page like this:

[image]